# How to efficiently order a list of lists using a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
mylist = [['dog', ['dogs details']], ['cat', ['cats details']], ['rat', ['rats details']], ['rabbit', ['rabbits details']], ['mouse', ['mice details']], ['goat', ['goats details']]]
```

I also have a names list as follows.

```
mynameslist = ["fish", "rabbit", "cow", "cat", "dog", "owl", "rat", "mouse", "parrot", "goat", "emjenne", "emj"]
```

I want to order `mylist` considering the order of `mynameslist`. i.e. my output should be as follows.

```
mylist_new = [['rabbit', ['rabbits details']], ['cat', ['cats details']], ['dog', ['dogs details']], ['rat', ['rats details']], ['mouse', ['mice details']], ['goat', ['goats details']]]
```

I tried to do this as follows.

```
mylist_new = []
for item in mynameslist:
   for val in mylist:
       if val[0] == item:
           mylist_new.append(val)
           break
```

However, I have really long `mylist` and `mynameslist`. Since my code is O(n^2) it takes a lot of time to create `mylist_new`. I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this with less time.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a *map* from animal name to index:

```
>>> namemap = {e:i for i,e in enumerate(mynameslist)}
```

And then use that as a key for `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: namemap[x[0]])
[['rabbit', ['rabbits details']], ['cat', ['cats details']], ['dog', ['dogs details']], ['rat', ['rats details']], ['mouse', ['mice details']], ['goat', ['goats details']]]
>>>
```

This will be O(N*logN) same as `sorted` now, since `namemap[x[0]]` will be constant time.

Alternatively, depending on if your data is well behaved, you can do this in O(N), make a map out of your original list:

```
>>> animal_map = dict(mylist)
```

Then iterate over the names list using the map to reconstruct:

```
>>> [[name, animal_map[name]] for name in mynameslist if name in animal_map]
[['rabbit', ['rabbits details']], ['cat', ['cats details']], ['dog', ['dogs details']], ['rat', ['rats details']], ['mouse', ['mice details']], ['goat', ['goats details']]]
>>>
```

This will not work if there are duplicates in `mylist`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted` or `sort` (to sort inplace) with `key` parameter like this:

```
mylist = [['dog', ['dogs details']], ['cat', ['cats details']], ['rat', ['rats details']], ['rabbit', ['rabbits details']], ['mouse', ['mice details']], ['goat', ['goats details']]]
mynameslist = ["fish", "rabbit", "cow", "cat", "dog", "owl", "rat", "mouse", "parrot", "goat", "emjenne", "emj"]
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: mynameslist.index(x[0]))
#mylist.sort(key=lambda x: mynameslist.index(x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[['rabbit', ['rabbits details']],
 ['cat', ['cats details']],
 ['dog', ['dogs details']],
 ['rat', ['rats details']],
 ['mouse', ['mice details']],
 ['goat', ['goats details']]]
```

Edit: as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, this is fast to implement to slow on complexity (O(N^2)) so if the list is big you should consider using his answer instead